# Is there a way to "shuffle" the order that event listeners will be called?

Tags: c#, events, random, event-handling

I setup a test console application using the below code:

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var myEventGenerator = new EventGenerator();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            new EventListener(myEventGenerator);

        while (Console.ReadLine().Length == 0)
            myEventGenerator.TriggerEvent();
    }
}

class EventListener
{
    private static int numberOfInstances = 0;
    private int instanceNumber;

    public EventListener(EventGenerator eg)
    {
        eg.EventHappened += EventHappened;
        instanceNumber = numberOfInstances++;
    }

    void EventHappened(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Event Caught in Instance " + instanceNumber);
    }
}

class EventGenerator
{
    public event EventHandler EventHappened;

    public void TriggerEvent()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Event Begin");
        if (EventHappened != null)
            EventHappened.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
        Console.WriteLine("Event End");
    }
}
```

And the output of the application is:

```
Event Begin
Event Caught in Instance 0
Event Caught in Instance 1
Event Caught in Instance 2
Event Caught in Instance 3
Event Caught in Instance 4
Event Caught in Instance 5
Event Caught in Instance 6
Event Caught in Instance 7
Event Caught in Instance 8
Event Caught in Instance 9
Event End
```

Seems that the event listeners are triggering based on the order that they subscribed to the event.

But what if I don't want those event listeners to occur in that order?  What if I want it to be random?  Or, if I want to specify a different order?  Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't any way to change the order in which the event handler invokes the events hooked up to it. Check out [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664605%28VS.71%29.aspx) for more info.

Here is the important snippet:

> Invocation of a delegate instance whose invocation list contains
>   multiple entries proceeds by invoking each of the methods in the
>   invocation list, synchronously, in order. Each method so called is
>   passed the same set of arguments as was given to the delegate
>   instance. If such a delegate invocation includes reference parameters
>   (Section 10.5.1.2), each method invocation will occur with a reference
>   to the same variable; changes to that variable by one method in the
>   invocation list will be visible to methods further down the invocation
>   list. If the delegate invocation includes output parameters or a
>   return value, their final value will come from the invocation of the
>   last delegate in the list.

If you want this kind of control, you'll have to write some sort of class that does it for you.

Comment: +1 For the link.  Very good example executed there which paints a picture of what is possible/impossible with delegates.